# I want to search a pattern [Severity Level: Critical] in whole file in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have tried the below code, but it is checking line by line and want to check it in whole file. Please help me out in writing the correct code, once i get the pattern break it and says pattern is found else pattern is not found

```
set search "Severity Level: Critical"
set file [open "outputfile.txt" r]
while {[gets $file data] != -1} {
    if {[string match *[string toupper $search]* [string toupper $data]] } {
        puts "Found '$search' in the line '$data'"
    } else {
        puts "Not Found '$search' in the line '$data'"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is “small” with respect to available memory (e.g., no more than a few hundred megabytes) then the easiest way to find if the string is present is to load it all in with `read`.

```
set search "Severity Level: Critical"
set f [open "thefilename.txt"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

set idx [string first $search $data]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    puts "Found the search term at character $idx"
    # Not quite sure what you'd do with this info...
} else {
    puts "Search term not present"
}
```

If you want to know what line it is in, you might split the data up and then use `lsearch` with the right options to find it.

```
set search "Severity Level: Critical"
set f [open "thefilename.txt"]
set data [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set lineidx [lsearch -regexp -- $data ***=$search]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    puts "Found the search term at line $lineidx : [lindex $data $lineidx]"
} else {
    puts "Search term not present"
}
```

The `***=` is a special escape to say “treat the rest of the RE as literal characters” and it's ideal for the case where you can't be sure that the search term is free of RE metacharacters.

---

The `string first` command is very simple, so it's easy to use correctly and to work out whether it can do what you want. The `lsearch` command is not simple at all, and neither are regular expressions; determining when and how to use them is correspondingly trickier.